# Error in Oracle PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I got an error at

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28110: policy function or package VPD1.COLUMN_SEC_PACKAGE has error
```

Please help me. While implementing column level security in oracle, I got the error.

**Procedure:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package body COLUMN_SEC_PACKAGE
 is
  FUNCTION TEST_SEC( OWNER VARCHAR2, OBJNAME VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
   is v_SQL VARCHAR2(2000):='1=0';
  begin
     IF (SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SESSION_USER') ='VPD1')
     THEN
         v_SQL:=NULL;
     END IF;
     RETURN V_SQL;
  end;
  /
```

**PL/SQL to Add Policy**

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY (object_schema => 'VPD1', 
                           object_name => 'employee',
                           policy_name => 'VPD1_POLICY_COLUMN1',
                       function_schema => 'VPD1',
                       policy_function => 'COLUMN_SEC_PACKAGE.TEST_SEC',
                     sec_relevant_cols => 'salary');
 END;
 /
```

Answer (score 4):

You can see the error from the package using `show errors` immediately after executing the statement, or with `select * from user_errors where name = 'COLUMN_SEC_PACKAGE'`.

Your package body is missing an `END`; you have one for the function but not for the package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package body COLUMN_SEC_PACKAGE is
  FUNCTION TEST_SEC( OWNER VARCHAR2, OBJNAME VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 is
    v_SQL VARCHAR2(2000):='1=0';
  begin
    IF (SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SESSION_USER') ='VPD1') THEN
      v_SQL:=NULL;
    END IF;
    RETURN V_SQL;
  end;  -- end of function
-- no end for the package
/
```

It's helpful to specify what you are ending at each point so you can easily pick out what is missing; indentation helps that too of course. You also haven't shown a `/` after the package specification, which might just be an copy-and-paste mistake. You need to run both commands, with a `/` after each:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE COLUMN_SEC_PACKAGE AS
  FUNCTION TEST_SEC (OWNER VARCHAR2, OBJNAME VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2;
END COLUMN_SEC_PACKAGE;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE package body COLUMN_SEC_PACKAGE is
  FUNCTION TEST_SEC( OWNER VARCHAR2, OBJNAME VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 is
    v_SQL VARCHAR2(2000):='1=0';
  begin
    IF (SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SESSION_USER') ='VPD1') THEN
      v_SQL:=NULL;
    END IF;
    RETURN V_SQL;
  end TEST_SEC;
END COLUMN_SEC_PACKAGE;
/
```

Comment: Hi sir, its showing no errors after executing show error command.

Comment: below is the link which i am trying to implement. please help me.      http://www.sqlpanda.com/2013/03/virtual-private-database-vpd-3-limit.html?showComment=1394181496376#c6353690719546850175

Comment: actually package contains END while copying i missed the word

Comment: this is the below error i got after issuing show errors                Errors for PACKAGE BODY COLUMN_SEC_PACKAGE:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0      PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
1/14     PLS-00304: cannot compile body of 'COLUMN_SEC_PACKAGE' without  its specification

Comment: @user3391904 - so... the specification isn't there, which might be because of the missing `/`. But I'm unsure if you've posted exactly what you ran, or where you're running it. If you only create the package body (with errors), you can add the policy, but will get ORA-28110 when you select from the table.

Comment: @user3391904 - if you create the package specification (`create package`) and body (`create package body`) as shown, then the policy can be added and you can select from the table. If you don't create the specification, or have the `end;` missing, then you can add the policy but will get ORA-28110 on `select`. Make sure you have run both `create` commands properly.

Comment: sir please check the below link i am useing the same http://www.sqlpanda.com/2013/03/virtual-private-database-vpd-3-limit.html?showComment=1394181496376#c6353690719546850175

Comment: @user3391904 - you are not, or you wouldn't be getting the error. The `PLS-00304` means you have not run the `create package column_sec_package ...` command properly. Run `select object_type from user_objects where object_name = 'COLUMN_SEC_PACKAGE'` and you'll get one row back with `PACKAGE BODY`; you would also have a `PACKAGE` entry if you'd run both commands. **Make sure** you have the `/` on a line on its own after the `create package` statement, it's missing on your duplicate question too.